# Mounting a webdav share to its original Linux server

Tags: webdav, fstab, automount

Ok, so normally, a server provides a webdav share, and that can be accessed by mounting it on some other computer.
What I want to do is to mount it (permanently) not elsewhere, but on the actual Ubuntu server that is providing it.
My questions:

1. Is it possible?

   1.a if yes, how is it done properly?
2. Is it safe?

I have already tried it by inserting the following line into /etc/fstab (of the server):
`https://my.example.com/remote.php/webdav /home/ben/owncloud davfs auto,uid=ben,gid=ben,-netdev,rw 0 0`

This isn't working as intended, because at startup, it turns out to be not mounted, and it says only root can mount, EDIT: exactly *every other time* I reboot.
Also, last time I was experimenting with the options, chaos ensued and the server went down for a while (but maybe for a completely unrelated reason), so now I'm afraid to try again until I gather some more information...
To elaborate why I'm doing this: What I'm trying is to upload files from my phone to the server's webdav via rsync. However, I cannot mount the webdav on my phone, - hence, the idea to mount it on the server itself.

Comment: Does your phone support rsync? Your solution to this problem makes NO sense.

Comment: Yes, it does, out of the box. It's a Jolla. Why exactly doesn't it make sense?